# TypeError #1009 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, typeerror, flash-cs6

May I know what kind of errors are this? And what are they telling me?
How should I fix these errors?

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Options()

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Options/setName()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at fl.controls::TextInput/handleKeyDown()

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

An object that evaluates to null can have no properties. This error can occur in some unexpected (though valid) situations. For example, consider the following code, which creates a Sprite object.
Since this Sprite object is never added to the display list (via the `addChild()` method of a `DisplayObjectContainer object`), then its stage property is set to null, and as such, its stage property cannot have any properties. So the code generates the errror:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var q:String = sprite1.stage.quality;
```